# How do I setup a docker image to dynamically pull app code from a repository?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm using docker cloud at the moment. I'm trying to figure out a development to production workflow using docker with docker compose to pull application code for multiple applications of the same type, but simply changing the repository each pulls from. I understand the concept of mounting a volume, but all the examples show the source code in the same repo with the dockerfile and docker compose file. [example](https://github.com/b00giZm/docker-compose-nodejs-examples/tree/%C3%A5master/00-basic-express-generator). I want the app code from this example to come from a remote, dynamic repo. Would I set an environment variable in the docker image? If so how?
Any example or link to a workflow example is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If done right, the code "baked" into Docker images should be immutable and the only thing that should change at runtime is configurable parameters like environment variables (e.g. to set the port the app will listen on).

Ideally, you should bake your code into the image.  Otherwise you're losing a lot of the benefit of using Docker in the first place.

Comment: I should add that if you need to deploy new code, you should be deploying a totally new image.  Your build / deploy pipeline should accommodate this accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

#### The problem is..

.. your use case does not match with the best practice. You want an image without any code embedded in it, but rather fetched at each update. If you browse [the docker hub](http://hub.docker.com/) you'll find **many** image named as *service:version*. That's one of the benefit of Docker, offering different versions of the same service. If you want to always get the most up-to-date code your workflow may have some down sides.

#### One solution could be

[Webhooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook), especially if your code is versionned on [GH](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/). Or any tools of [continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration).